# Assign an Object to a String

Tags: java, string, object, stack

I am writing a program that generates a maze and then finds a path. I store all my moves into a stack called `visitStack` (if I move north, I store "N" into it, if Northeast then "NE", on and on). For part of my backtracking I need to be able to take the data from the stack and reverse my steps if I hit a dead end, but I've hit a snag here.

I need to assign a value popped from a stack to a `String` variable, but I always get a compiler error. I've tried using `toString`, instantiating the String as an object with the popped stack value as the parameter, and still can't get it. I've been on this for about an hour. Here is the code and error message.

```
String direction = visitStack.pop();
```

[image]

Comment: you have to type cast explicitly. String direction = (String) visitiStack.pop()

Comment: Please add some information about `visitStack` to your question so you can have more precise answers.

Comment: If every element of your stack is a string, perhaps it should be typed as a `Stack<String>`? We can't see the rest of your code, which makes it hard to help you as well as we could otherwise... (But using `toString()` would get around the compile-time error, which means presumably something else when wrong - but again, you haven't told us what.)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using `java.util.Stack` I suspect that you didn't describe what type of elements it should store, which is why compiler sees return type of `pop` as `Object` (common ancestor of all types).

Also assuming that stack should store only String elements it should be declared as

```
Stack<String> visitStack = new Stack<String>();
```

Now compiler should see return type of `pop()` as `String` which will allow you to store its result in other `String` type reference

```
String direction = visitStack.pop();
```

---

Above solution is ***preferred*** when you are sure that stack can contain only strings, but if there are some other elements you will need to either explicitly cast returned object to String (if you are sure that it will be instance of String) like

```
String direction = (String) visitStack.pop();
```

or if you are not sure what object will be returned calling `toString()` method to get its string representation:

```
String direction = visitStack.pop().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define your stack as `Stack<String>`, `pop()` will return a `String`, and you won't need to mess around with casting. If you cannot, for some reason, and you're positive the object being popped is a `String`, you can cast it explicitly:

```
String direction = (String)visitStack.pop();
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a limited number of possible values you shloud use ENUMS for type Safety.

Use :

```
Stack<Direction> visitStack=new Stack<>();
visitStack.push(Direction.EAST);

Direction dir=visitStack.peek();

String dir2=visitStack.pop().toString();

System.out.println(dir);
System.out.println(dir2);
```

your Direction should look like:

```
public enum Direction {
North("N"), NORTH_WEST("NW"), NORTH_EAST("NE"), EAST("E")
, SOUTH_EAST("SE"), SOUTH("S"), SOUTH_WEST("SW"), WEST("W");

private String shortName;

private Direction(String shortName) {
    this.shortName = shortName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.shortName;
}
}
```

Comment: This enum can be simplified a little with `private String shortName` field, constructor which will set that filed like `North("N")`, and toString (or other method), which will return `shortName`.